# Discrepancy between $\dim H^2(G, \mathrm{ad}(\bar \rho))$ and the number of relations in a minimal presentation of the universal deformation ring $R$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\ad{ad}\DeclareMathOperator\gen{gen}$Let $p$ be a prime and $G$ be a profinite group such that the pro-$p$ completion of every open subgroup is topologically finitely generated. Let us fix a continuous residual representation $\bar\rho:G\to \GL_n(\mathbf{F}_p)$ where $\mathbf{F}_p$ is a finite field of order $p$. If $(A,\mathrm{m})$ is a complete local $\mathbf{Z}_p$-algebra with residue field $\mathbf{F}_p$ where $\mathbf{Z}_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers, then a deformation $\rho$ of $\bar
\rho$ to $A$ consists an equivalence class of homomorphism $\rho:G\to \GL_n(A)$. Mazur showed that there exists a universal deformation ring $R_{\bar \rho}$ if $\bar \rho$ is absolutely irreducible and $R_{\bar \rho}$ has a presentation $R_{\bar \rho}=\mathbf{Z}_p[[X_1,\cdots,X_h]]/J$ for some ideal $J\subset \mathbf{Z}_p[[X_1,\cdots,X_h]]$ where $h:=h^1(G,\ad(\bar \rho)):=\dim_{\mathbf{F}_p} H^1(G,\ad(\bar \rho))$ here $\ad(\bar \rho)$ is the adjoint representation of $\bar\rho$, and the minimal number $\gen(J)$ of generators of $J$ satisfies $$\gen(J)\leq h^2(G,\ad(\bar \rho)):=\dim_{\mathbf{F}_p} H^2(G,\ad(\bar \rho)).$$
My question is the following:

1. In general, how to compute $\Delta:=h^2(G,\ad(\bar \rho))-\gen(J)?$
2. When do we have $\Delta=0?$
3. If $R_{\bar\rho}=\mathbf{Z}_p$,then is it true that $h^2(G,\ad(\bar \rho))=0?$ More general, if $R_{\bar \rho}=\mathbf{Z}_p[[X_1,\cdots,X_h]]$ is the ring of formal power series over $\mathbf{Z}_p$, then is it true that $h^2(G,\ad(\bar \rho))=0?$

Answer (score 2):

Question 3: No. In fact for any ring $R$ that appears as a deformation ring, $R$ can be a deformation ring of a group with arbitrarily large $h^2$.

It suffices to find, for $G$ a group with representation $\rho$, a group $G' $ with a surjection to $G$ whose kernel has no nontrivial map to $\mathbb Z/p$, but such that $h^2( G', \operatorname{ad} (\overline{\rho}))$ is sufficiently large. Then any deformation of $\rho$ as a $G'$-rep is already a deformation as a $G$-rep, so the deformation rings are the same.

To do this, note that for $W$ a vector space  over $\mathbb F_p$, $\operatorname{ad} (\overline{\rho}) \otimes W \oplus W^\vee$ has a canonical central extension by $\operatorname{ad} (\overline{\rho})$ which is preserved by the $GL(W)$ action, so $$(\operatorname{ad} (\overline{\rho}) \otimes W \oplus W^\vee) \rtimes GL(W)$$ has a central extension by $\operatorname{ad} (\overline{\rho})$,  and then

$$((\operatorname{ad} (\overline{\rho}) \otimes W \oplus W^\vee) \rtimes GL(W))^m \rtimes G,$$ with $G$ acting through its action on $\operatorname{ad} (\overline{\rho})$, gives the desired $G'$.

Comment: Why does $((\operatorname{ad} (\overline{\rho}) \otimes W \oplus W^\vee) \rtimes GL(W))^m$ have no nontrivial map to $\mathbb{Z}/p$ and what is $h^2(G', ad(\bar\rho))$?

Comment: @Nobody It's classical that $GL(W)$ has no notrivial map to $\mathbb Z/p$ since its abelianization has order $p-1$, so any such map must be nontrivial on $(\operatorname{ad} (\overline{\rho}) \otimes W \oplus W^\vee) $. Maps from $(\operatorname{ad} (\overline{\rho}) \otimes W \oplus W^\vee) $ to $\mathbb Z/p$ are classified by elements of the dual vector space but the only ones that extend to the semidirect product are the $GL(W)$-invariant ones, which all vanish since the dual vector space is a sum of copies of $W$ and $W^\vee$.

Comment: @Nobody $h^2$ can probably be calculated by a Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence argument. All I need to do is lower bound it, and it's not hard to check it goes up by at least $m$ since each copy adds a new central extension.

Comment: thanks for your counterexamples. Perhaps the answer to Question 3 is Yes when $G=G_{K,S}$ is the Galois group of the maximal extension of some number field $K$ unramified outside some finite set $S$ of places of $K$.

Comment: @Nobody I suspect, but didn't check carefully, that the techniques in the results mentioned here https://www.galoisrepresentations.com/2022/04/23/murphys-law-for-galois-deformation-rings/ can also be used to give a negative answer to your modified question - roughly, any technique that can be used to ensure there is a class in $H^2$ giving an arbitrary relation in the deformation ring can probably be used to ensure that there is a class in $H^2$ giving no relation at all.